# Self-closing tags affects performance of web applications (ASP.NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, iis-7

I have here a question. I just want to know if this error:

"HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag. 
index.aspx, line 1094 character 41"

affects the performance of my web application. I see it using Internet Explorer. Does this error really affects the performance of my web application? And can you give me a valid article that will support if it really affects or not ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If it's generating an error, then the code has to find and generate the error, making a hinderance on your performance. Close your tags properly.

Comment: hi @RUJordan, i believe my code doesn't generate an error. becuase on other client machines it is working very well. And lets assume that in vb/cs code we dont have an error becuase the other environment where I published this web application doesn't encounter this performance issue. They blaming that warning message as the cause of the performance issue.